# Are `yarn link` and `npm link` interoperable?

Tags: npm, yarnpkg, npm-link, yarn-link

I know there are subtle differences between `yarn` and `npm`. Now I have a library managed with yarn and an app managed with npm.

*Should* it work without issues, if I create a linked pkg in my lib directory via yarn and apply it via npm in my other directory? Or should I expect issues with this setup? If yes, which issues might pop up and how could I avoid them (*except* converting both projects to the same manager)

```
~/the-lib$ yarn link 
~/app$ npm link @the/lib
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a year old, but I stumbled across it while trying to answer this for myself. Here's my setup:

- library package: NPM
- client package: YARN

When I tried using `npm` and `yarn` as described in the question it did not work.

But, I was able to run `yarn link` successfully in my npm package, and then `yarn link lib-name` in my client package.

So, it works!